# Get Unicode for Nexmo inbound messages

Tags: vb.net, unicode, sms, vonage

I am trying to use Nexmo for inbound messages. I tested with standard GSM and it worked pretty fine, but when I send unicode it appears as "???????".

The details for the received parameters :

```
msisdn:6019xxxxxxx (My No that I sent from)
type:unicode
to:447937947888
network-code:
messageId:030000000DA63B29
message-timestamp:2013-01-13 03:43:13
text:????? ?????
concat:
concat-ref:
concat-total:
data:
udh:
```

Is there an option to get the message text as Unicode, then I can convert it to text?

Comment: With `type:unicode` you must use UCS-2 not GSM